reset password send link even to non registred accounts
I have an issue in my reset password code. If the user put an email that is not registered, it also send him the reset link. I want only the registered emails only, and if they are not registered it prompt them that there is no account with this email.
This is the code snippet :
Future<void> resetpassword(BuildContext context) async {
   try {
     await FirebaseAuth.instance
         .sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _email.text.trim());
     Navigator.of(context).pop();
     showDialog(
         context: context,
         builder: (context) {
           return AlertDialog(
             content: Text('Password reset link sent! Check your email.'),
           );
         });
       } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
         String errorMessage = 'An error occurred. Please try again later.';
         if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
           errorMessage = 'No user found with this email.';
         } else if (e.code == 'invalid-email') {
           errorMessage = 'The email address is not valid.';
         }

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text(errorMessage),
          );
        });
    log('Error resetting password: ${e.code}, ${e.message}'); // Log the error code and message for debugging
  } catch (e) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text('Failed to send reset email. Please try again.'),
          );
        });
    log('Unknown error: $e'); // Log unexpected errors
  }
}

I tried a lot of solutions, but nothing worked.

On newer projects Firebase has auto-enabled the protection against email enumeration attacks, which makes it impossible to detect whether a specific email address exists in the project (as that's precisely what this type of attack uses). So you'll either have to find another way to implement the use-case, or disable the protection.

firstly u have to check there is any users in database with given email :
Future<bool> userExists(String email) async {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  try {
    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: 'TemporaryPassword123!', // Use a temporary password
    );

    // If the account creation is successful, delete the account and return false
    await userCredential.user!.delete();
    return false;
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
      // If account creation fails because the email is already in use,
      // return true
      return true;
    } else {
      // If account creation fails for any other reason, return false
      return false;
    }
  }
}

and then add a if statements and look is there any users :
bool isUserRegistered =  await userExists(_email.text.trim());

if (!isUserRegistered) {
await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _email.text.trim());
// and another things...
}
else {
// show error message etc.
}


or if u are storing users in your database, u can query is there any users with given email instead of using my userExists function.
